# Laravel + Vue js Deploying on Shared hosting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, shared-hosting

I have a `Laravel` project that already deployed on shared hosting server but now I just want to add `Vue.js` component to that project.

Problem is when I was deploying project I didn't install the `npm`. Can anyone advise me how to fix this thing. I used `Laravel 5.8`

How can I add `Vue` component to this project ?

Comment: Did you try Laravel Mix?

Comment: You don't need npm to compile the Vue components, just run `npm run production` in your local computer, Laravel mix will compile all files to /public folder, that's the folder you need to make sure to upload to your shared hosting, you only need npm to local development.

Answer (score 0):

you can't run npm commands in sharing hosting .

you can run `npm run production` in local and share mixed file on sharing hosting

Comment: Should I do this when I making changes every time in local

Answer (score 0):

Usually shared hosting does not provide enough shell commands. So you would need to run `npm run production` on your local computer.

As a reminder, it is not recommedable to host Laravel website on a shared host. You may need to do extra work to make your Laravel website work such as changing document root of your laravel project.

Comment: What is the better solution you suggest? should I move to cloud hosting?

Comment: A few Google searches or searching on Laracast, which is the community for Laravel, will give you some hints :) Cloud hosting is a good option.